# How do I copy files to a machine based on a vars flag using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get a playbook to copy a different set of files to a server, depending an a flag set on the group it belongs too in the ansible inventory.

The code is as follows

```
      - name: check if they exist already
       stat:
         path: /home/me/set1files
       register: st
     - name: copy pre-prod if they don't
       copy:
         src: /home/me/set1files
         dest: /home/me
         owner: me
         group: me
         mode: "0644"
      when: (st.stat.exists==false) and (is_emms_pp==true)

     - name: check if prod files exist
       stat:
        path: /home/me/set2files
      register: stprod
     - name: copy prod files
       copy:
         src: /home/me/set2files
         dest: /home/me
         owner: me
         group: me
         mode: "0644"
      when: (stprod.stat.exists==false) and (is_emms_pp==false)
```

and in the inventory file

```
  [PPEMMS]
  emmspp1
  emmspp2
  emmspp3

  [PPEMMS:vars]
  is_emms_pp = true
                                                                                                                              
  [PRODEMMS]
  emms1
  emms2
  emms3

  [PRODEMMS:vars]
  is_emms_pp = false

  [EMMS:children]
  PPEMMS
  PRODEMMS
```

When I run the script on a new PP machine, it all seems to work fine, but when I run it on a new Prod machine, it still copies the PP files and skips the step for the Prod machine.

Is this a valid test or do I have something wrong?

One thought I had was that because I'm limiting the script to one machine, rather than the group, its not picking up the group_var?

I'm using the script as

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts -l emms1 install_emms.yml  --ask-vault-pass  --extra-vars '@passwd.yml'
```

For each machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `is_emms_pp = true` is a string. Quoting from [Defining variables at runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime)

> "*Values passed in using the key=value syntax are interpreted as strings. Use the JSON format if you need to pass non-string values such as Booleans, integers, floats, lists, and so on.*"

Given the inventory to simplify the test

```yaml
test_01 is_emms_pp=true
test_02 is_emms_pp=false
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test_01,test_02
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: is_emms_pp|type_debug
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  is_emms_pp|type_debug: str
ok: [test_02] => 
  is_emms_pp|type_debug: str
```

Comparison between a string and a boolean will fail

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Copy file
      when: is_emms_pp == true
```

gives

```yaml
skipping: [test_01]
skipping: [test_02]
```

One option is to compare strings. The task below works as expected

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Copy file
      when: is_emms_pp == 'true'
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: Copy file
skipping: [test_02]
```

The cleaner option is to convert the variable to boolean. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Copy file
      when: is_emms_pp|bool
```

See [CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#conditional-bare-vars)

---

Example of how to fix the conditions

```yaml
    - name: check if they exist already
      stat:
        path: /home/me/set1files
      register: st
    - name: copy pre-prod if they don't
      debug:
        msg: Copy set1files
      when:
        - not st.stat.exists
        - is_emms_pp|bool

    - name: check if prod files exist
      stat:
        path: /home/me/set2files
      register: st
    - name: copy prod files
      debug:
        msg: Copy set2files
      when:
        - not st.stat.exists
        - not is_emms_pp|bool
```

Comment: If I could upvote more than once I would.. Thank you.